# Is there any way get datarow from datatable without using foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

**Controller**

```
foreach (DataRow temp in act.Rows)
{
    _oResolutionModel.activityNo = temp["ActivityID"].ToString();
    _oResolutionModel.assignTechnician = temp["TechNo"].ToString();
    _oResolutionModel.recommendation = temp["RECOMMENDATION"].ToString();
    _oResolutionModel.jobStart = (DateTime)temp["JobStart"];
    _oResolutionModel.jobEnd = (DateTime)temp["JobEnd"];
        _oResolutionFacade.setResolutionID(_oResolutionModel.activityNo);
        DataTable res = _oResolutionFacade.getResolution(_oAppSetting.ConnectionString);
        foreach (DataRow x in res.Rows)
        {
            _oResolutionModel.solution = x["Resolution"].ToString();
            _oResolutionModel.remarks = x["Remarks"].ToString();
            _oResolutionList.Add(_oResolutionModel);
            break;
        }
    _oResolutionList.Add(_oResolutionModel);
    break;
}
```

In here my **_oResolutionList** count = 1, meaning there's two data in it and it duplicated the first data. I want to have only 1 data in my **_oResolutionList**. Do I need to add some code in my inner Foreach or should I change something on it.?

Or You can suggest me how to delete the second data entry.?

Comment: teresko, Thanks for the edit

Comment: I found **break;** at the end of for loop. So you want only first row of your dataTable ??? If yes then there is no need of for loop...

Comment: I try not using foreach but in declaring my **Datarow temp;**. it can get the datatable value. that's why I'm using Foreach.

Comment: If you want to access the row of your dataTable then you can access it like this - **act.Rows[0]["ActivityID"].ToString();** OR **act.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();**. Here i have wrote act.Rows[0] bcs i guess you want only first row right ???

Comment: You don't need to use break inside foreach loop

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, nope. before I use foreach, I put this code ** DataTable act = _oActivityDetailsFacade.getActivityDetails("0000001", _oAppSetting.ConnectionString);** so that I can get the datatable of the *0000001* which is the id of the row.

Comment: @inanikian, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `foreach` loop. You can also check the nullity first and then assign.
You can also do :

```
  _oResolutionFacade.setResolutionID(_oResolutionModel.activityNo);
    DataTable res = _oResolutionFacade.getResolution(_oAppSetting.ConnectionString);
     _oResolutionModel.solution = res.Rows[0]["Resolution"].ToString() ?? string.Empty; //To make sure that if it is null it will assign to an empty string
     _oResolutionModel.remarks = res.Rows[0]["Remarks"].ToString()?? string.Empty;
```

You have many solutions to deal with that.
Hope it will help you

Comment: It didn't work, even I put a **DataRow x;** and if I don't declare it the error will be **'x' doesn't exist in the current context** still there's an error **cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'**

Comment: @seeyahlater, I am sorry. It is the variable `res` not `x`. Typo.

Comment: res[0] error: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.data.data.table'

Comment: Have a try. Some typo made.